# Angular TypedForms - optional FormControls

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a typed FormGroup based on the following interface. Note that proId is optional:

```
interface FormData {
    name: FormControl<string>;
    age: FormControl<number | null>;
    active: FormControl<boolean>;
    proId?: FormControl<number>;
}

constructor(private formBuilder: NonNullableFormBuilder) {}

form: FormGroup<FormData> = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: '', // will be initialized in ngOnInit when @Input() can be accessed
  age: null as number | null, // will be initialized in ngOnInit when @Input() can be accessed
  active: false as boolean,
  proId: 0
});
```

But how to initialize the proId FormControl correctly? With my solution above I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type 'FormGroup<{ name: FormControl<string>; age: FormControl<number>; active: 
FormControl<boolean>; proId: FormControl<number>; }>' is not assignable to type 
'FormGroup<FormData2>'.   Type 'FormControl<number> | undefined' is not assignable to type 
'FormControl<number>'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<number>'.
```

And a second question:

Is it the correct way to initialize the following two fields like this:

```
age: null as number | null
active: false as boolean
```

Because if I only use

```
active: false
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'FormControl<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<false>'.     Type 'boolean' 
is not assignable to type 'false'.
```

Comment: Interestingly, when we do `this.formBuilder.group({ ... }) as FormGroup<FormData>` it works, check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujscag)

Answer (score 2):

In typed form when we use FormBuilder, We need to define formControl to each key explicitly

**Try this:**

```
 form:FormGroup<FormData> = this.formBuilder.group<FormData>({
  name: this.formBuilder.nonNullable.control(''), 
  age: this.formBuilder.control(null),
  active: this.formBuilder.control(false),
  proId: this.formBuilder.control(0) 
 });
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1hkpbl?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you very much! It's a shame that this isn't documented.

Comment: You are welcome . I raised issue in angular doc https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46275